# SAP HANA - Aggregate dates by ranges in SQL Script

Tags: hana, hana-sql-script

I have this table `EFF` on SAP HANA:

```
OBJECT;PN;MANUFACTURER;MONTH;QTY   
OBJ1;PN1;MAN1;201601;1   
OBJ1;PN1;MAN1;201602;1   
OBJ1;PN1;MAN1;201603;2   
OBJ1;PN1;MAN1;201604;1   
OBJ1;PN1;MAN1;201605;1   
OBJ1;PN1;MAN1;201606;1
```

I would like to obtain with a SQL statement an aggregated view of the table by `OBJECT` / `PN` / `MANUF` / `QTY` but **sorted by date**. Here is what I want:

```
OBJECT;PN;MANUFACTURER;DATE_FROM;DATE_TO;QTY    
OBJ1;PN1;MAN1;201601;201602;1 (from 01-2016 to 02-2016, OBJ1 contained 1 PN1)   
OBJ1;PN1;MAN1;201603;201603;2 (from 03-2016 to 03-2016, OBJ1 contained 2 PN1)   
OBJ1;PN1;MAN1;201604;201606;1 (from 04-2016 to 06-2016, OBJ1 contained 1 PN1)
```

I've already tested many solutions but nothing works well... I always obtain :

- 1 line from 01-2016 to 06-2016 with qty = 1
- 1 line from 03-2016 to 03-2016 with qty = 2

It is not enough ...

I've been looking to Window functions in SAP HANA like `FIRST_VALUE` (partition by...) and `LAST_VALUE` but it's not working properly...

Do you have any idea, please ?

---

*Note : I already have implemented a Stored Procedure with a Cursor to do it, and it works (in several hours), but I need something much faster. Because it concerns billions of lines.*

Comment: The desired logic is not clear yet. Do you want a new grouping whenever the QTY changes? In that case, you should look for "finding longest streak" examples with window functions.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Lars. Yes I do want a solution grouping lines by quantities but respecting the chronological order. I'm writing a solution  based on `LEAD` / `LAG` and `ROW_NUMBER` functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to get is as following

```
select 
    "OBJECT", 
    PN, 
    MANUFACTURER, 
    Month as fromMonth, 
    Lead(Month,1) over (partition by  "OBJECT", PN, MANUFACTURER Order by Month) as toMonth,
    sum(Qty) as qty 
from EFF
group by
    "OBJECT", 
    PN, 
    MANUFACTURER,
    Month
```

Output with your sample data is as in below screenshot

[image]

As you mentioned I used the [SQL Lead function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/lead-function-in-sql-server-2012-for-next-value.aspx) for calculating next month 
I used Group By clause for SUM() aggregate function to collect Quantities per month on the bases of Object, PN and Manufacturer

I hope it helps,